# is there a way in R such that the value of a column should be the one above if it meets a certain criteria in another column

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, row, bigtable

I want the value in `myrate` column to be

1. for the first value of `myrate` should be `rupee` (minus) `amt`
2. for second row of `myrate` column should be the first value of `myrate` (value as generated in point 1) minus the second value of `Rupee` column if 'Name' is the same in both the 1st and second row
3. the logic of step 2 should continue till a new value in `Name` colume is reached (in this case: "sss")
   4.again in the second row of "sss" name, the logic of step 2 should continue

I tried using `dplyr` which gives the correct answer for some iterations, but it fails for others.

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNavY.png)

Comment: Can you show the data with `dput` and expected output

Comment: Name Amt Rupee Myrate
kkk 20 11 -9
kkk 21 333 -342
kkk 22 65 -407
sss 23 90 67
sss 24 36 31
sss 25 71 -40
ttt 26 69 43
ttt 27 32 11   (myrate column is the expected output)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I added a helper function to compute `myrate`. Instead of checking names I simply split the df by `Name`, do the computations for each `Name` and bind them back together in the end.

```r
# Example data

df <- data.frame(
  Name = c(rep("kkk", 3), rep("sss", 3), rep("ttt", 2)),
  Amt = c(20:27),
  Rupee = c(11, 333, 65, 90, 36, 71, 69, 32)
)
df
#>   Name Amt Rupee
#> 1  kkk  20    11
#> 2  kkk  21   333
#> 3  kkk  22    65
#> 4  sss  23    90
#> 5  sss  24    36
#> 6  sss  25    71
#> 7  ttt  26    69
#> 8  ttt  27    32

# Helper function
myrate <- function(df) {
  # Init myrate = 0
  df$myrate <- 0
  # Add id = row number
  df$id <- 1
  df$id <- cumsum(df$id)
  # Loop over id or rows
  for (i in df$id) {
    df$myrate[i] <- 
      if (i == 1) {
        df$Rupee[i] - df$Amt[i]
      } else {
        df$myrate[i] <- df$myrate[i - 1] - df$Rupee[i]
      }
  }
  df["id"] <- NULL
  df
}

# Computation
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  # Split by Name
  split(.$Name) %>%
  # Compute myrate for each Name
  lapply(myrate) %>%
  # Bind back in one df
  bind_rows()
#>   Name Amt Rupee myrate
#> 1  kkk  20    11     -9
#> 2  kkk  21   333   -342
#> 3  kkk  22    65   -407
#> 4  sss  23    90     67
#> 5  sss  24    36     31
#> 6  sss  25    71    -40
#> 7  ttt  26    69     43
#> 8  ttt  27    32     11
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Stefan, thans for the revert, just one doubt, what if the line items in the tables are really huge, like few 100s..please also provide help in such case

Comment: Hi Shailesh. As you tagged your question with `bigtable` I was aware that using a for loop is probably not the best solution. In general it should work for a large table, however it is probably quite slow. In this sense it's only a first step on how to implement the algorithm. Unfortunately, at the moment I have no quick solution to get rid of the loop. Therefore I would recommend that you build up on my first step and ask a second and refined question on how to implement the algorithm without the need of a for loop.

Comment: Dear Stefan, Appreciate your time and effort spent on helping me out. Thanks a lot